# Due to MDLable ID does not have get attribute how to override on this

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

As I'm new learner on kivy language with python. Here is my code:

```py
    from kivy import app
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
    from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
    from kivy.properties import  ObjectProperty
    from datetime import timedelta 
    from datetime import datetime
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    
    Builder.load_string('''

    <TOolBar_Window>:
    #timeday: timeday
    name:'Main_Window1'
    RelativeLayout:
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'Main_Window1'
            elevation: 10
            right_action_items: [['logout']]
            pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":1}

        MDLabel:
            id: timeday
            #text: "name"
            markup:True
            halign:'center'
            multiline:True
            ''')

    class TOolBar_Window(MDScreen):
    pass  

    class MainApp(MDApp):
        #timeday = ObjectProperty(None)
        def build(self):
       
           self.sm= ScreenManager()
           self.sm.add_widget(TOolBar_Window(name ='tolBar_Window1'))
           return self.sm

        def on_start(self):
             Clock.schedule_interval(self.dell,1)

        def dell(self,nap):
        
           self.nap=datetime.now()
           self.nap = self.nap + timedelta(seconds = 1)
           self.day = self.nap.strftime('%A')
           self.date = self.nap.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
           self.time = self.nap.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
           self.root.ids.timeday.text = self.day+'\n'+self.date+'\n'+self.time
        if __name__ == '__main__':  
            MainApp().run()
```

In my code I get a error like this:

> self.root.ids.timeday.text = self.day+'\n'+self.date+'\n'+self.time
>
> File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
>
> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

If i remove this line:

```py
self.root.ids.timeday.text =self.day+'\n'+self.date+'\n'+self.time
```

Then code is running and but time and date not updated. I also trying with object property but still not get same error. I also try parents widgets but not use with this error:

> 'super' is substituted with the real value, because well... it doesn't have **getattr**,To keep my answer brief, here's the minimalistic object that extends Scatter object.,super gives you an access to a class you inherit from,I suspect(not sure) that if you use string as the value for id, you'll end up with weakref / WeakProxy pointing to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `root` widget.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import  ObjectProperty
from datetime import timedelta 
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.clock import Clock


kv = ('''

<TOolBar_Window>:
    name:'Main_Window1'

RelativeLayout:
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Main_Window1'
        elevation: 10
        right_action_items: [['logout']]
        pos_hint: {"left":1, "top":1}

    MDLabel:
        id: timeday
        #text: "name"
        markup:True
        halign:'center'
        multiline:True
''')


class TOolBar_Window(MDScreen):
    pass  


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
       self.root = Builder.load_string(kv)
       self.sm= ScreenManager()
       self.sm.add_widget(TOolBar_Window(name ='tolBar_Window1'))
       self.root.add_widget(self.sm)
       return self.root

    def on_start(self):
         Clock.schedule_interval(self.dell, 1.0)

    def dell(self,nap):
       self.nap=datetime.now()
       self.nap = self.nap + timedelta(seconds = 1)
       self.day = self.nap.strftime('%A')
       self.date = self.nap.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
       self.time = self.nap.strftime('%I:%M:%S')
       self.root.ids.timeday.text = self.day+'\n'+self.date+'\n'+self.time


if __name__ == '__main__':  
        MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so and got it know how to called root widgets in code